# How in xsl-fo to add fixed text in the last column on every page except the last?

Tags: xsl-fo

I need to get a document that has multiple columns (for example, two) . At the very end of the document, there is a fixed text (date and signature). In addition, each page, except for the last one, should also have a similar fixed text with a date and signature at the very end of the last column. But if there is only one page in the document, then the fixed text should only be at the end of the document.

Example with multiple pages:

```
(page 1)
some text some text     some text some text
some text some text     some text some text
some text some text     some text some text
some text some text     some text some text
some text some text     some text some text
some text some text     some text some text
some text some text     some text some text
some text some text
some text some text     date
some text some text     signature

(page 2)
some text some text
some text some text
some text some text

date
signature
something
```

Example with a single page:

```
some text some text     some text some text
some text some text     some text some text
some text some text     
some text some text     date
some text some text     signature
some text some text     something
some text some text
some text some text
some text some text
some text some text
```

How to get such a document using xsl-fo?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am new to using xsl-fo, so due to my ignorance I tried using:

1. float tag;
2. block-container tag with the attribute position= "absolute";
3. static-content tag in region-end"

but all this did not lead to the desired result.

Comment: Would it look okay if the date and signature are in the page footer (`xsl:region-after`) on pages other than the last page?

Comment: Unfortunately not, since "signature" in the final required version will consist of several lines (about 10) that excessively increase the region-after area.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AH Formatter, then you could put your text in a single-column table and put the repeated content in `fo:table-footer`.  If you then put `table-omit-footer-at-break="column"` on the `fo:table`, the footer will appear only at page breaks.  See https://www.antenna.co.jp/AHF/help/v70e/ahf-ext.html#axf.table-omit-footer-at-break.

The `something` would presumably be in an `fo:block` immediately after the `fo:table`.

Comment: A good idea, but unfortunately, I have to use FOP, and the table-omit-footer-at-break attribute doesn't have the "column" value available in it (only "true" and "false").

Comment: I started with "If..." because it wasn't clear what you were using.  It's unfortunate that's not an option for you.